# Changing custom CSS attributes without Javascript?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

So I am doing some wiki editing, and sadly Javascript is not enabled. Therefore, I need help from the CSS guru's out there!

I understand you can add a custom HTML attribute like this:

```
<span id="some-id" custom_attr="no"></span>
```

And you can style elements with `custom_attr` like this:

```
span[custom_attrib] { /* styling here */ }
```

Now, is there a way to edit the HTML attribute inside the CSS?

Example (which does not work of course..):

```
<!------------- CSS ------------>
<style>
  .some-class {
    /* Original code here */
  }
  .some-class[custom_attr = "yes"] {
    /* Change code here */
  }

  #some-id:hover ~ .some-class[custom_attr = "no"] {
    custom_attr : "yes";
  }
</style>

<!------------- HTML ------------>
<html>
...
<span id="some-id">...</span>
<span class="some-class" custom_attr="no">...</span>
...
</html>
```

Comment: no you can't change attr with CSS

Comment: `Now, is there a way to edit the HTML attribute inside the CSS?` No.

Answer (score 7):

Of course you can edit the HTML with CSS!

From your example code, it looks like you want to change the "No" to "Yes" when the user `hovers` on it. Here's how:

http://jsfiddle.net/ENZQU/

```
<a default="YES" mouseover="NO"></a>

a {
    font-size: 3em;
}
a:after {
    content: attr(default);
}
a:hover:after {
    content: attr(mouseover);    
}
```

Did you want it on `click` instead? Easy!

http://jsfiddle.net/ENZQU/1/

```
<input id="cbox" type="checkbox">
<label for="cbox"></label>

#cbox {
    display: none;
}
label {
    font-size: 3em;
}
label:after {
    content: "YES"
}
#cbox:checked + label:after {
    content: "NO"
}
```

I strongly suggest that you find another way to do this, though. The wiki doesn't want you to dynamically change things on the page, and it's probably built that way for a reason.

Comment: You can also add a click toggle state via `:focus` provided you add a `tabindex` attribute in the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/ENZQU/4/

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you can't change your HTML code with CSS, you just can do that with JavaScript.

Andy Davies proposed that feature to CSS in her [personal blog](http://andydavies.me/). I think this is a really interesting proposal. You can see and join the discussion created by Andy Davies [here](http://andydavies.me/blog/2012/08/13/what-if-we-could-use-css-to-manipulate-html-attributes/). 
[image]

CSS 3 is amazing, how we can know if in near future CSS don't will have something like that?

---

### **The question is:**

You **really** can't use JavaScript in your page? This is the only way you can change your HTML code, CSS just style the HTML.

You can be sure about [that in the W3C](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/), the people who "develop the web".

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I know CSS is only for styling. But people have done some amazing things with pure CSS, including dropdown menus and tabbed documents. The `hover` pseudo-class is amazing, but sadly there is no way to change states on mouse click.

Comment: Yet @Jacob-IT, CSS 3, as you said, is really amazing. I can't wait for CSS 4. Just to know what the creativity and CSS 3 can do, see this link: http://www.muktware.com/2013/11/developer-creates-simpsons-entirely-css/15784

Comment: Edited the answer, hope this can help you more.