# Expand/collapse mobile navbar without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

On mobile devices, Bootstrap 3 by default reduces the navigation bar (navbar) to a hamburger icon. When clicking the hamburger, a JavaScript toggles the display of the navigation menu items - either expanding or collapsing the navbar. But

## how to toggle the bootstrap mobile navbar collapse/expand without requiring JavaScript?

If this were possible, it would have nice **performance advantages**: users can already navigate before JavaScript is executed (a good plus on flaky mobile connections), and smaller projects may be able to drop the dependency on jQuery + bootstrap javascript entirely, saving around 45k on first page load. Plus, the site becomes more  **robust in case of JS errors** - at least the page navigation stays usable.

Alternatively, one could [re-implement the bootstrap JS without jQuery dependency](http://thednp.github.io/bootstrap.native/) - done [here](http://mpetroff.net/2015/03/bootstrap-navbar-without-jquery/) for the navbar.

For reference, this is what the [static navbar top](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/) example looks like in mobile mode:

[image: Bootstrap 3 mobile navbar expanded]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it's possible!

## Getting the BS3 mobile navbar to toggle without JavaScript

1. creating a hidden checkbox that contains the navbar state (expand if checked)
2. changing the navbar `button` to a `label` for this invisible checkbox
3. use the [CSS General Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) to toggle display of the navbar.

How to change CSS attributes without JavaScript was discussed before on SO, and the principle shown there [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009469/changing-custom-css-attributes-without-javascript). Applying this bootstrap is straightforward.

Try the **[Live demo](https://cdn.rawgit.com/basteln3rk/bs3-navbar-collapse-without-javascript/master/index.html)** thanks to [rawgit](https://rawgit.com/) or see it in production on [flexponsive](https://www.flexponsive.net/)

A full demo is available on Github project [bs3-navbar-collapse-without-javascript](https://github.com/basteln3rk/bs3-navbar-collapse-without-javascript).

## Browser Support

- the CSS general sibling selector is widely supported
- successfully tested in mobile: Android 5 and iOS 8
- also works on desktop: Chrome 43 and Firefox 38

## Limitations

- dropdowns still require JS, if you decide to use them

## Steps in detail

First, custom CSS you need to add:

```css
/* show the collapse when navbar toggle is checked */
#navbar-toggle-cbox:checked ~ .collapse {
    display: block;
}

/* the checkbox used only internally; don't display it */
#navbar-toggle-cbox {
  display:none
}
```

Then change the navbar HTML as follows:

```
<!-- insert checkbox -->
<input type="checkbox" id="navbar-toggle-cbox">
<!-- change the "hamburger" icon from being a button to a label for checkbox -->
<div class="navbar-header">
 <label for="navbar-toggle-cbox" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </label>
<!-- end label not button -->
```

Comment: Great answer. Quick follow up - how do you then toggle the navbar-toggle-cbox to be closed once you click on one of the elements in the collapsed navbar? Can you do this using pure CSS?

Comment: Good question - not sure how to do that yet. Can you explain your use case? I use this code for sites entirely without JS, so a click on the nav items triggers a complete page reload

Comment: I am using AngularJS, for routing, so when I click on a item in the navbar dropdown, it doesn't fire a complete page reload (i think). So the page loads below the navbar dropdown, and the navbar doesn't re-collapse.

Comment: I see - in this case you will probably need to work with Angular/JavaScript somehow

Comment: This doesn't seem to work : https://jsfiddle.net/2k9bb8hd/, can you post a snippet here?

Comment: @basj Did you try the live demo linked above

Comment: @user3096626 `404 Not Found / nginx`.

Comment: https://cdn.rawgit.com/basteln3rk/bs3-navbar-collapse-without-javascript/master/index.html works for me?

Comment: CHECKOUT THE ACCEPTED ANSWER https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170781/show-hide-divs-on-click-in-html-and-css-without-jquery