# Collapse without javascript

Tags: css, html

I know how to collapse (display / hide) a div:

```js
$('#nav').click(function() { $('#hello').toggleClass('hidden'); });
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav">NAV</div>
<div id="hello" class="hidden">Hello</div>
```

**Is it possible to do this without Javascript / jQuery?**

*I've tried the main answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506684/expand-collapse-mobile-navbar-without-javascript), but it is not working, as detailed [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2k9bb8hd/).*

Comment: Well, yes, it is, but it's really ugly.

Comment: there were some selector parts missing in your example. here's the fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/2k9bb8hd/2/

Comment: The fiddle works if you actually add an element with class name `collapse`: https://jsfiddle.net/2k9bb8hd/3/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You may use `:checked` selector.

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
:checked + #hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox" style="display:none;">
<div id="hidden"></div>

<label for="my_checkbox">Show/hide</label>
```

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3uhj9e7/)

Comment: This is really clever

Comment: This is basically the idea from the answer linked in OP's question

Comment: @DenisSheremet Thanks! PS: by the way do you know a nice CSS hamburger icon? I browsed many SO questions but didn't find a really good looking one...

Comment: Thanks a lot @DenisSheremet ! Here is my variation: https://jsfiddle.net/sgbs7ju9/4/

Comment: How can I make the red box appear after the button instead of before?

Comment: @Kos just swap div and label and leave checkbox where it is. You'll also need to update css selector to `:checked ~ #hidden` or `:checked + * + #hidden`.

Answer (score 51):

Nobody has mentioned the 'details' element, which seems perfect for this job.

```html
<details>
    <summary>Click to toggle</summary>
    <span>Oh, hello</span>
</details>
```

Comment: amazing, no css, no js solution

Answer (score -2):

Well yes, it is, but it's not neat. It involves the `:target` selector, where you can apply styles to *active* elements / id's. If we wrap your nav content in a link, we can apply a hashtag which invokes the active rule in our CSS.

Downside, this jumps the page to the location unless prevented by... JavaScript.

```css
a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
  
#hidden {
  display: none;
}

#hidden:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav"><a href="#hidden">NAV</a></div>
<div id="hidden">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Oh, woops! I ment `:target`.